# How to use firebase UI with bslib in shiny?

Tags: r, firebase, shiny, bslib

In a normal shiny app, the UI container from `firebase` works fine. But with `bslib`, it throws an error. See the example below.

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(firebase)
    
ui <- page_navbar(
  useFirebase(),
  firebaseUIContainer(),
  
  title = "title",
  sidebar = sidebar("Sidebar"),
  nav_panel("P1", "Page 1 content"),
  nav_panel("P2", "Page 2 content"),
  nav_panel("P3", "Page 3 content"),
  nav_panel("P4", "Page 4 content")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  f <- FirebaseUI$new()$set_providers(
    email = TRUE,
    google = TRUE)$launch()
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Error: Navigation containers expect a collection of `bslib::nav_panel()`/`shiny::tabPanel()`s and/or `bslib::nav_menu()`/`shiny::navbarMenu()`s. Consider using `header` or `footer` if you wish to place content above (or below) every panel's contents.
```

I am not sure how to use `header` or `footer`. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The firebase UI container and the rest of the app show up correctly if I do:

```
header = div(useFirebase(),
  firebaseUIContainer())
```

inside `page_navbar()`.